# python list element address decrease instantly

Tags: python, element, memory-address

I just wrote the code like this:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for ele in li:
    print "value: ", id(ele)
```

and I got the result:

> value:  21381944 1
>   value:  21381920 2
>   value:  21381896 3
>   value:  21381872 4
>   value:  21381848 5

24 bytes are allocated to each element, but I don't understand why the address of each element decrease rather than increase.

Comment: Why would you expect the addresses to increase?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga A better question would be "why do you think these addresses should even be sequential?"

Comment: FYI, the `id` is not the address, it is a unique ID for an object (it *could* be the address, this is implementation dependent).

Comment: @DeepSpace yes, indeed.

Comment: ugh memory just doesn't work like you think it does, leave it there for now

Comment: @SteveHaigh, yes, I got wrong meaning for id and I know that it's a unique mark for an object.

Answer (score 1):

These are the memory addresses that reference the objects. You can't deduce anything from them regarding the objects' size.

These can be in any particular order. They may even be non-sequential.

Doing this experiment with integers in the range -5 to 256 may be misleading since Python caches integers in this range.

Let's test this with arbitrary objects:

```
class A: pass

i = [A(), A(), A()]
for ele in li:
    print("value: ", id(ele))

# value:  36309936
# value:  36310000
# value:  36310032
```

Obviously every `A` instance will have the same size in memory, but the difference between the first and second ids is 64 but between the second and the last is 32.

Let's run it again with another `A` instance:

```
li = [A(), A(), A(), A()]
for ele in li:
    print("value: ", id(ele))

# value:  36441008
# value:  36441072
# value:  36441104
# value:  36472912
```

64 between the first and the second, 32 between the second and the third, and 31808 between the third and the fourth.

You can play around with this for as long as you want:

```
li = [A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A()]
for e1, e2 in zip(li, li[1:]):
    print(abs(id(e1) - id(e2)))

# 192
# 32
# 32
# 32
# 44093952
# 2524224
# 2551328
# 15147712
# 64
# 128
# 32
```

The idea of the list being a list of references to objects and not a list of objects can be visualized by using a memory visualizer such as [this one](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20A%3A%20pass%0A%0Ali%20%3D%20%5BA%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29,%20A%28%29%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=2&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).